# Tableau: Dashboard Parameter

Tags: tableau-api

I change my start date and end date parameter to a relevant date range, and I was able to switch the filters in the worksheet.  How do I change the parameter in the dashboard? I was able to remove the start and end date parameter from the dashboard, but unable to add the new relevant date parameter in the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Analysis -> Parameters option in the Main menu. This should show all the Parameters present in the worksheet on your dashboard. If it is not visible then make sure that you have the correct worksheet on your dashboard and the Parameter is enabled for filtering in the sheet present on your dashboard. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to add Parameter to your Dashboard
1) Select Analysis (on bar menu) -> Parameters -> 
2) Right-click on any of the Sheet shown in your Dashboard -> Parameters ->